# Why is my TCPServer not accepting multiple client connections?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have written below TCP server, I don't know why handler is not supporting multiple TCP client connections.

```
import socket
import sys
import ast

# Internal imports
import core
try:
    import fcntl
except ImportError:
    fcntl = None
import logging
import json

_LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    import SocketServer
    TCPServer = SocketServer.TCPServer
    RequestHandler = SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    import socketserver
    TCPServer = socketserver.TCPServer
    RequestHandler = socketserver.BaseRequestHandler


class TCPServerRequestHandler(RequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        """Receives data from client.
        """
        msg = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        if self.client_address and not msg:
            _LOG.error("No Data revieved from Client: {}".format(self.client_address[0]))
            return
        # Send some data to client
        # self.wfile.write("Hello Client....Got your message".encode())
        data = ast.literal_eval(msg.decode('utf-8'))
        if not data:
            _LOG.error("No data recieved.")
        else:
            with core._connect(db="exampledb") as conn:
                if "device" in data and data["device"] == "mcu":
                    table_name = "roku_online_status"
                    if conn:
                        data.pop("device")
                        cols = [c for c in data.keys()] # python 3 dict keys is not list
                        stored_value = core.doQuery(conn, table_name, cols, "id")
                        if stored_value[0] != data["online"]:
                            core.insert_row(data, table_name, conn)
                else:
                    if conn:
                        core.insert_row(data, "particle_photon", conn)
                conn.close()


class Server(TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    # The constant would be better initialized by a systemd module
    SYSTEMD_FIRST_SOCKET_FD = 3

    def __init__(self, server_address, handler_cls, bind_and_activate=True):
        self.handlers = set()
        # Invoke base but omit bind/listen steps (performed by systemd activation!)
        try:
            TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler_cls, bind_and_activate)
        except TypeError:
            TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler_cls)

        # Override socket
        self.socket = socket.fromfd(
            self.SYSTEMD_FIRST_SOCKET_FD, self.address_family, self.socket_type)

        if fcntl is not None and hasattr(fcntl, 'FD_CLOEXEC'):
            flags = fcntl.fcntl(self.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFD)
            flags |= fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
            fcntl.fcntl(self.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFD, flags)

    def server_bind(self):
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

    def server_close(self):
        TCPServer.server_close(self)
        print("Shutting down server.")
        for handler in self.handlers.copy():
            print(handler)
            self.shutdown_request(handler.request)


def main(server_address):
    """Starts TCPServer.
    """
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    # Create a TCP Server instance
    server = Server(server_address, TCPServerRequestHandler)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(("10.10.10.2", 7111))
```

For a single connection it works just fine, but when multiple clients tries to connect it gets stuck.

Comment: It gets stuck where?

Answer (score 2):

You have implemented a single-threaded server with blocking I/O. This kind of server can only handle a single client at a time since it waits until the client is done (inside `TCPServerRequestHandler`) before it will be able to process the connection of the next client.

To handle multiple clients at the same time you either have to use multiple threads or processes where each can handle a single client or you have to implement an event based server which can handle multiple clients inside a single thread. To implement the first you might have a look at the [ThreadingTCPServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer) and [ForkingTCPServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer) and for the latter have a look at frameworks like [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).